# Passing Environment Variable to NetworManager GUI

Tags: centos, gnome3, networkmanager, openvpn

My VPN stoped working when I switched to Centos 7.  I narrowed the problem to the lack of MD5 support (not strong enough).  I followed this [thread](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=47210#p200973), and now I can use open-vpn on the command-line to make a connection.  However I still cannot use the Gnome GUI (I did try [this](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=47210#p201728) but no cigar).

Is there a way I can pass environment variables to the NetworkManager GUI?

Comment: Have you rebooted after changing the NM service file?

Comment: @"Cristian Ciupitu" Yes I did reboot.  I even started using an environment file...but couldn't get it to work.